# Bash: Why does this Brace Expression work this way?

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

this is a bash 4 specific question. I am somewhat familiar with the bash Brace Expressions and I have read the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) but I do not understand how it actually works.

I guess it has to do with the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) but I am not used to searching the bash source code to confirm it so my question is this:

Why does this `echo {G..a}` expand to

```
G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [  ] ^ _ ` a
```

Comment: It does not have to be the ASCII table. It depends on your locale.

Comment: I guess each charset uses a different ASCII table. My guess is that there is a loop somewhere in the code. The start and end delimiters are encoded in hex or dec and each element is printed with it's printable counterpart. With a different locale I guess one can indeed expect different results. Does this make the brace expressions not portable, even when bash 4 is guaranteed to be used?

Comment: Yeah you are right, if you run echo {G..a} you will get the output I mentioned. I will edit my question, which still remains though.

Comment: See also https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2015-07/msg00135.html (which explains the missing backslash)

Comment: ASCII *is* a charset; if you have a different character set than ASCII, then ASCII tables don't apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `bash` manual (with my emphasis):

> A sequence expression takes the form `{x..y[..incr]}`, where `x` and `y` are
>          either integers or single characters, and `incr`, an optional increment,
>          is an integer.  When integers are supplied, the expression expands to
>          each number between `x` and `y`, inclusive.  Supplied integers may be
>          prefixed with `0` to force each term to have the same width.  When either
>          `x` or `y` begins with a zero, the shell attempts to force all generated
>          terms to contain the same number of digits, zero-padding where
>          necessary.  **When characters are supplied, the expression expands to
>          each character lexicographically between `x` and `y`, inclusive, using the
>          default C locale.**  Note that both `x` and `y` must be of the same type.
>          When the increment is supplied, it is used as the difference between
>          each term.  The default increment is 1 or -1 as appropriate.

Brace expansions with letters as ranges allows for mixed-case ranges in `bash`.
So what you are seeing are the characters between `G` and `a` in the ASCII table (with a default 1 increment as the values occur in that order in the table).

Between the last uppercase character (`Z`) and the first lowercase character (`a`) in the standard ASCII table, there are the characters

```
[ \ ] ^ _ `
```

in this order.

You do not get `\` in your output as the shell would treat an escaped space character as a literal space.  Also note that since an unquoted backtick is outputted, this could potentially lead to unexpected code execution, as [pointed out by Stéphane](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2015-07/msg00135.html) in a message to the `bug-bash` mailing list in 2015.

I do however not quite know what the manual refers to as "type", but my guess would be that you can't use a letter and a digit, as in `{1..z}` (which indeed does not expand).

Comment: I didn't know that it is always the C locale. Seems I have mixed it up with `[a..z]`.

Comment: See also https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2015-07/msg00135.html

Comment: "Type" seems to refer to integer/char. So `{3..z}` won't work.

Comment: @WeijunZhou I just realised :-)

Comment: @WeijunZhou So...Bash has the concept "Type" or it just know your string is in "number form" so reject your operation?

Comment: I believe it's the latter. There is `declare -i` but that's unrelated to the brace expansion here.

Comment: Thank you for clearing some points for me, it does make sense now. What seems a bit weird though is the  "must be of the same type" part. Since bash uses the ASCII table corresponding to the default C locale, why can expressions like {1..z} not work? Also, since `[` and `]` are characters, why does {a..]} or even {[..]} not work (escaped or not)? Also +1 for the security heads up, appreciated!